# Need a PPA for the latest GCC

Tags: ppa, gcc

I'm looking for a PPA with the latest and greatest version of GCC. I'm too scared to switch to something totally unstable and knock my production system out of wack, but want the newest version of GCC. Additionally I don't want to waste tons of time building my own version of GCC.

Comment: Contradiction much? you want the latest and greatest, yet you don't want it to be unstable?... bleeding edge is not for you then, stick to what you have if instability is not what you want.

Comment: Ubuntu has 6.4.1 GNU has 4.6.2 as stable. GCC 4.7.0 is unstable. The cool distros have 4.6.2 in their stable repos.

Comment: So..?, if you're about to use GCC you should know how to compile software anyways. Ubuntu is not a rolling release distro you know that.. the repositories are frozen before Ubuntu is released and whatever the version of the software is at that point (should the developers send their packages to Canonical) that's the version that you'll get.

Comment: Your only option is to wait for someone to create a PPA and upload THAT specific version of GCC, PPAs are not maintained by Canonical,  and neither is this site is affiliated to them so you can't just come here and REQUEST a PPA.

Comment: @if you're about to use GCC you should know how to compile software anyways... I know how to do it and I know it will take me a few hours.

Comment: That will be faster than waiting for someone else to create,compile, and upload a package to a PPA...

Comment: OP are you still looking for an answer? If so, you may need to repost your question as this is flagged for closure. Regards,

Answer (score 3):

This is documented here: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ToolChain

The toolchains that are currently being used to build 12.04 should be there, I think, although that page is slightly out of date.